# replacing img src attribute w/ jQuery not working

Tags: jquery, replace, slideshow, src, attr

I'm trying to create simple slideshow where if I click the image it will turn into the next image. So far I have four images in a subfolder, named 1-4 (ex: 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg, 4.jpg). 
I've set up a counter (the variable imgcounter) so that if it is greater than 4 it will reset to 1, and I use this counter to easily change the src name of the img element.

The simple version:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var imgcounter = 1; 
$('#slide img').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
        if(imgcounter <= 4 ) {
            imgcounter++;
            $(this).attr('src', 'images/' + imgcounter + '.JPG');
        } // end if
        else {
            var imgcounter = 1;
            $(this).attr('src', 'images/' + imgcounter + '.JPG');
        } // end else
    }); // end click    
}); // end each
});  // end ready
```

In this version the image will not even change if I click it.

I've also tried this more complicated method where I put a variable to define what I want to replace source with. I'm not sure if I'm using the replace() function right, especially at the part where I used double apostrophes '' to indicate I want to replace the entire src. I'm also not sure if I wrote out the second part of the replace() function legitimately -- the 'images/' + imgcounter + '.JPG'.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var imgcounter = 1; 
$('#slide img').each(function() {
    var imgFile = $(this).attr('src');
    var preloadImg = new Image();
    $(this).click(function() {
        if(imgcounter <= 4 ) {
            imgcounter++;
            preloadImg.src = imgFile.replace('', 'images/' + imgcounter + '.JPG');
            $(this).attr('src', preloadImg.src);
        } // end if
        else {
            var imgcounter = 1;
            preloadImg.src = imgFile.replace('', 'images/' + imgcounter + '.JPG');
            $(this).attr('src', preloadImg.src);
        } // end else
    }); // end click    
}); // end each
});  // end ready
```

In this version the image changed but I get a broken image symbol and the error console reads:
Failed to load resource file:///..(took out full path)../images/1.JPGimages/1.JPG
I'm not sure why it's failing to replace the entire source and instead it just seems to append a copy of the source name at the end...

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Hmm in the first version if I place "var imgcounter = 1;" right below the click() function, the first click works and the image changes. But then if I click the image again it will not move to the next image.

Comment: You don't really need the `.each()` function. Also, you're redeclaring the variable `imgcounter` in the `else` block.

Comment: hmm you're right. Didn't catch that. Would I need an each() function if I had multiple image elements?

Comment: the `$("#slide img")` selects all children `img` elements of `#slide`, so no, I don't think you would.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do something like:

```
var imgcounter = 1;

$("#slide img").click(function(e){
    if(imgcounter < 4){
        imgcounter++;
    }else{
        imgcounter = 1;
    }
    $(this).attr("src", "images/"+imgcounter+".jpg");
});
```

It adds the handler to each `img` inside `#slide` anyway, so no need for the `each()` function, and it looks a lot cleaner.
Also, removed the redundant call to `$(this).attr()`.

Comment: wow that worked perfectly and the code is so simple! Except I don't think that "e" is supposed to be in function()?

Thanks!!

Comment: `e` is the event object that gets passed through to the handler automatically. You can manipulate the event using it if you really wanted. But in this case, you're right, it provides no added value.